# Ruby string to date time format

Tags: java, ruby, date, functional-programming

I have multiple dates coming in from user input, examples:

```
MM-DD-YYYY

6-3-1975

MM/DD/YYYY

4/23/1967
```

using the ruby built in `require 'time'`

and trying to `Time.parse("4/23/1967")`

gives me the error time.rb : `argument out of range`.

Any solutions to convert different user inputs with either dashes or slashes to parse?

Comment: So what is your desired input format?

Comment: The user can enter the inputs shown... The problem is I am trying to convert the different formats coming in to one format... MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: So you just want to force all the user input to end up in the form MM/DD/YYYY? I was a little confused as to what you are trying to accomplish with `Time.parse`

Comment: ```time = Time.parse("4/23/1967")```
```time.strftime("%m/%d/%y")``` -- would allow me to convert to my format.

Comment: Is the answer I put down what you need? If not could you possibly try to edit your question to expand on what you need and clarify the question?

Comment: For Java, search for "java date" to find hundreds of Questions and Answers with discussion and example code for parsing strings into date-time objects. Tip: look at Joda-Time and java.time while avoiding java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat like the plague.

Comment: The problem is, you don't know the locale of the use, which would tell you their preferred date format. You are assuming they are US-centric, which is a bad assumption. ASK your user so you know, then use `strptime` to parse into the correct format or a form that doesn't allow them to type in the month and date values, but instead uses popups or select boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
require 'date'

userDate = "4-23-1967"
readDate = Date.strptime(userDate, "%m-%d-%Y")
convertedDate = readDate.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y")
puts convertedDate

OUTPUT: 4/23/1967
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
Time.parse("23/4/1967")
#=> 1967-04-23 00:00:00 +0100
Time.parse("3-6-1975")
#=> 1975-06-03 00:00:00 +0100
```

So the problem is that your month and day order is reversed.

Comment: It's not my problem... the user is putting in MM/DD/YYYY, so I have to convert it to the right format which still doesn't work.

Comment: Then maybe you can try this one liner:

    Time.parse(date.match(/^(\d+)[^\d](\d+)/).captures.reverse.push(date.match(/[^\d](\d{4})$/)[1]).join('-'))

Comment: @AntonB, "I have to convert it to the right format". What happens if one user is U.S. based and uses "MM/DD/YYYY", and another is based somewhere else in the world that uses "DD/MM/YYYY". Are you arbitrarily going to switch MM values with DD? You can't do that as some of the time the dates will fail and sometimes the month and day values will be reversed. You will have introduced a very annoying bug at that point. You *HAVE* to ask the user what date format they want to use, or use a form that doesn't allow them any opportunity to reverse them when entering months and days.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you should use `gsub` to replace the characters you don't want with the ones you do.

```
input = "6-3-1975"
sanitized_input = input.gsub(/[- ]/, '/')
```

Inside the square brackets you can put any delimiter that your users are including that you don't want.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, it only postpones it.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @theTinMan could you elaborate?

Comment: The value `6/3/1975` is a format that Ruby will misinterpret to mean the day is "6" and the month is "3" unless more work is done to force Ruby to parse the string correctly. As a result, your answer only postpones the inevitable problem of a rejected string due to a value like `1/13/1975` and results in dates that `parse` will always misunderstand.